# UWP get data usage

Tags: c#, uwp

I love programming for UWP and I start new program with C# and UWP. I want to get network usage for each connection in the target system. I read document in MSDN and I write this code for my app:

```
public async static Task<List<ConnectionReport>> GetNetworkUsageAsync(string ConnectionName, DateTimeOffset StartTime, DateTimeOffset EndTime, DataUsageGranularity Granularity)
{
    var granularityTimeSpan = GranularityToTimeSpan(Granularity);
    try
    {
        var connectionProfile = GetConnectionProfile(ConnectionName);
        var networkUsages = await connectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(StartTime, EndTime, Granularity, new NetworkUsageStates());
        List<ConnectionReport> listNetworkUsage = new List<ConnectionReport>();
        foreach (var networkUsage in networkUsages)
        {
            var connectionReport = new ConnectionReport()
            {
                Date = StartTime.Date.ToString(dateFormat),
                Download = ConvertBytesToMB(networkUsage.BytesReceived),
                Upload = ConvertBytesToMB(networkUsage.BytesSent),
            };                                     
            listNetworkUsage.Add(connectionReport);
            StartTime = StartTime.Add(granularityTimeSpan);
        }
        return listNetworkUsage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        // do something
    } 
}         

private static ConnectionProfile GetConnectionProfile(string ConnectionName)
{
    var connectionProfiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
    foreach (var connection in connectionProfiles)
    {
        if (connection.ProfileName == ConnectionName)
            return connection;
    }            
}

private static double ConvertBytesToMB(double bytes) => Math.Round(bytes / 1024 / 1024, 3); 

// Returns the amount of time between each period of network usage for a given granularity
private static TimeSpan GranularityToTimeSpan(DataUsageGranularity granularity)
{
    switch (granularity)
    {
        case DataUsageGranularity.PerMinute:
            return new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        case DataUsageGranularity.PerHour:
            return new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        case DataUsageGranularity.PerDay:
            return new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
        default:
            return new TimeSpan(0);
    }
}
```

But I don't know my code have some problems or windows 10 build 15063 have some problems because I run my app on two different system and I get same value for all WiFi and Ethernet connections. I always get my network usage with this code but not for a special connection, It's give me my Internet usage however I choose 2 different WiFi.
Is it possible to say me that it is windows problem or my code have some problems?
Thanks.

Comment: This api is only supported on windows phones.  Are you trying on a windows phone?

Comment: Yes. it's work for windows phone but not windows. where you see that it is only work in Windows mobile not windows 10 and is there any way to get thing that I want.

Comment: It is an UWP app. I don't think that is only for windows mobile?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile

Comment: so is there any other way to get network usage for each connection?

Comment: @KenTucker Why did you say this api is only supported om windows phones? The document is only says that **GetAttributedNetworkUsageAsync** method is only supported in a Windows Phone Store app. **GetNetworkUsageAsync** should also works on desktop as it's a Universal API.

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice. GetNetworkUsageAsync is for both but it doesn't work. it work like NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile and get usage for Internet Connection profile!

Comment: I think GetAttributedNetworkUsageAsync  gets the usage from the phone carrier and that is why it only works on the phone.  Of course I cant find any documentation on how it works

Comment: I don't know how to solve my problem and there is no other place for ask question. I download network data form windows 10 store and it gives same value for all WiFi in my system and friend system. Is it windows 10 problem? does someone have lower version of windows 10 not 15063 and test it?

Comment: No one know how can I ask from Microsoft for problem?

Comment: I get an answer finally: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/e2c741db-7172-4f69-81e9-c2f21f4983d6/uwpc-get-data-usage?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Hi @AminBorjian, is it possible to adapt your code to get data consumption per network type? (wifi, cellular, roaming)