# UWP/C# Get the data usage per network type and per app

Tags: c#, networking, uwp, roaming, consumption

I'm looking for a way to analyze the **data consumption** from an UWP app. For this, I need to:

- get the **data usage** per newtork (wifi, cellular, roaming, ...)
- get the detailed information per **installed app**

In **Windows 10**, we can found these informations easily:

- for the [data usage](http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/data-usage-windows-10.png)
- for the [usage details](http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Check-and-Restrict-Monthly-Data-Usage.jpg) per app

***But how to get the same information in an app?***

The only closest topic I foud is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781041/uwp-get-data-usage), but it's not really the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, We can get the network usage from a network connection using the [ConnectionProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile) Class which provides information about the connection status and connectivity statistics.

For your **data usage**, you can try the following code,

```
try
{
    var ConnectionProfiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
    if (ConnectionProfiles != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ConnectionProfiles.Count);
        foreach (var profile in ConnectionProfiles)
        {
            //Profile name
            var name = profile.ProfileName;

            NetworkUsageStates networkUsageStates = new NetworkUsageStates();
            networkUsageStates.Roaming = TriStates.DoNotCare;
            networkUsageStates.Shared = TriStates.DoNotCare;
            //get the data usage from the last 30 day
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
            var usages = await profile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(startTime,
                endTime, DataUsageGranularity.Total, networkUsageStates);
            if (usages != null)
            {
                foreach (var use in usages)
                {
                    //Data usage.
                    var TotalDataUsage = use.BytesReceived + use.BytesSent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

You can configure different `DataUsageGranularity` and `NetworkUsageStates` to get the data usage you want.

But for your **usage details**, since UWP app run sandboxed, you can not get the detailed information, and there are no corresponding APIs in UWP.